# Do we need [vegan]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We already have a [veganism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/veganism) tag, on 55 questions.  It already has a tag wiki excerpt, though no tag wiki yet.

As a contrast, [vegan](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegan) is on 8 question with no wiki/wiki excerpt.

The tags appear to have the same meaning, both for questions about aspects of veganism.

Should we burninate [vegan](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegan) and/or synonymize it with [veganism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/veganism)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think [vegan](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegan) tag would be searched by some users. I suggest to synonymize it with [veganism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/veganism).