# Synonymize [vegan] with [veganism]?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, retag-request

[In this question](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64/do-we-need-vegan), the consensus is to make [vegan](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegan) a synonym of [veganism](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/veganism), the reason being that [vegan](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vegan) may still be searched and/or added to questions by new users.

Nobody has over 1250 rep to synonymize it. Can we get a SE employee and/or unicorn to do this for us?

Comment: Also make [vegan-diet] a synonym.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have suggested the synonym.

<strike>If you have enough points on the tag, you can [vote for it here](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/tags/veganism/synonyms)</strike>

It was voted into action by the community, so this is complete.